# Qt cannot provide real time "Window is being dragged" events

Tags: qt

Here's a simple task that looks innocent. Small Widget window. Whenever it's dragged around the desktop (by catching its titlebar with the mouse and moving it around) it should print out its X and Y position **IN REAL TIME.** during the move.

Sounds simple, but it seems it's impossible to do this in Qt.

No matter what I do, I cannot get real time events for when I catch the caption and move the window around. I have an event filter, but during drag only sporadic few events come in -- the moveEvents etc are only after I release the mouse button. I need real time events for every pixel of movement (or at least for every time the window is actually moves on the screen, as close a possible to real time)

Is there a way to do that without drilling holes into the OS?

I'm using Qt on Mac.

Comment: The real question is: does the OS actually provide such events. If it does, there's no need to drill any holes, just add a native event filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what came to my mind first. This solution does not provide the real time events handling, but I think it is **very close** to it. If you move your window slowly enough, you can catch movements in a pixel precision. Ok, now the implementation (I believe the code explains how it works):

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        m_timer.setInterval(1);
        connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimer()));
        m_timer.start();
    }

private slots:
    void onTimer()
    {
        if (m_lastPos != pos()) {
            // Window moved. 
            m_lastPos = pos();
            qDebug() << "Moved to:" << m_lastPos;
        }
    }

private:
    QPoint m_lastPos;
    QTimer m_timer;
};
```

Comment: yeah. I figured something like that may be the solution. Concerned about CPU usage which will be constant. But perhaps with smart management where you can catch the NonClient window title mouseDown event (when you start to drag) and NonCLient window title mouseUp event and start/stop the timer between those events only - it won't take up CPU when the app's in idle mode

Comment: Yes, correct. This example can be optimized and improved, of course.